# Putting PC to sleep after power failure

Tags: windows, sleep, automation

My question is this, how can I make my pc (windows 10) go to sleep mode after it comes back from a power failure if I don't log on in let's say 3 min.

In my head it's simple but I don't know how to do it.

1- check if pc came from a power off state

2- wait 3 mins for a user to logon

3- in case that fails to happen go in to sleep mode

Is it possible? My first guess would be with tasks but I don't know what events to look for

Thanks

If this is not the place to ask this question I'm sorry and could you please direct me somewhere where it is?

Comment: In Windows Advanced Power Management to Sleep after 20 minutes and then it should sleep even if not logged on.

Comment: Thanks but that is not the point, I don't want it to go to sleep if idle, I need to put it to sleep after a reboot caused by a power outage, when I'm not home and the power goes I need to put it to sleep so I can wake it remotely later if I need (witch I can already do)

Comment: The step I gave you should work 20 minutes after the power returns.  You could change the interval to 10 minutes or whatever. But that is what you said "put it to sleep after restart".  It cannot determine restart caused by power failure.

Comment: Sure hehe I figured as much its a log not magick :D. What I mean is that your solution would make my PC go to sleep if idle for 20 min, I sometimes need to have it working long hours unattended  and therefore apparently idle and going to sleep at those times is a no go. Again for the same reason if I'm not home or neãr and power goes out, I need to put my pc back to work, but if I can't do it right then I don't want  to be wasting energy.

Comment: As I understand it the logs are different when you power up the PC and when you wake it up from sleep mode, my intention would be to check only if it came from a complete shutdown/reboot before checking if someone logs on or not

Comment: After a power faulire Event ID 6008 (dirty shutdown - "The previous system shutdown at time on date was unexpected") will be generated at next startup. You can attach a task to this event telling the computer to enter sleep state.

Comment: That should do the trick and I don't even need to check for log on, it just boots and goes to sleep, I can wake it later a do my thing :) although if I'm home when it happens I need to to wait for it to go to sleep to continue working but  lesser evil, it should do the trick, thanks I'll try it as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

Using Event ID 6008 worked like a charm as the trigger for the task.

As for checking if user was logged in or not I first tried delaying the task by checking if the machine was idle but for some reason it would not run the command on my desktop, it did so on my laptop (just for testing purposes), so, I ended up using a cmd file with a time delay of 3 min and a second task that runs if I logon and disables the countdown, pretty ugly if you are a programmer looking at it I'm sure, but it does the trick for me so if it's not broken don't fix it, thankyou fuzzy for the tip.